# How access model data directly from view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am just a beginner in ASP.NET MVC. I know we can pass data of model to the View through the controller by using TempData/ViewData/Viewbag or by directly passing it as ActionResult.

I want to know, is there any way that we can directly access the members of Model class to a View?

Comment: You should really watch the tutorials on www.asp.net - and yes that is possible.

Comment: Oh.. you want to access the view inside the model? - Then no - don't do that.

Comment: @TGlatzer Thanks for your suggestion. I will keep it in mind not to follow this approach. But is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For such basic question of passing/accessing the model members in the view, you should first try to search some links/topics online, anyways here are few to get you started-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/04/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-pass-data-to-a-view.aspx

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you @Manik Arora for your answers, but all these above links are giving way to pass/ access data through Controller not directly accessing the Model data. It will be very helpful if you give me any examples.

Comment: @NibiPanda data can be passed to the view via controller only and using the ways which you have already specified in your question.